# perl: how to specific a alternative version?

Tags: perl

I have two versions of perl: 5.10 and 5.8. 5.10 is at `/usr/perl` and 
5.8 is at `/opt/perl`.

When I launch a perl script, it searches for 5.10. Is it possible to use some variable to tell it to 5.8 libs?

I don't want to change the PATH variable if possible.

Comment: Mixing libraries from different versions of perl will fail if there are incompatible XS changes between the different versions of perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the different Perl interpreter. Either by calling it explicitly:

```
/opt/bin/perl /path/to/foo.pl
```

Or by setting it in the shebang line:

```
#!/opt/bin/perl 
print "Hello World!\n"
```

You really don't want to use libraries from a different interpreter. Just switch interpreters.

Answer (score -2):

Solution found

```
export PERL5LIB=/opt/perl/libs
```

Comment: That doesn't use a different `perl` at all. If you want to change version, you'll either need to use a path, or use `perlbrew`.

Comment: Yes right,i forgot to specific not perl executable but alternative perl libs

Comment: Crossing over libs but not interpreter will cause you pain - they may not have been built for an older perl.

Comment: Right, i have accept the solution before my fake solution